# How to determine if I'm a user or admin?

Tags: php

If I'm a user I will go the user page and if I'm an admin I will go to the admin page. Here's my code

```
  <?php
     require('config.php');

     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
      $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
      $pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
      $pass = md5($pass);

      $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `uname` = '$uname' AND `pass` = '$pass'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($check) > 0){
       header("Location: adminhome.php");

      }
      else{

       echo "Wrong password";
      }
     }
     else{

      $form = <<<EOT
      <form action="login.php" method="POST">
     <p>Doesn't have an account yet? </p>
     <title>Login</title>
           <p align ="left"><a href="register.php">Register</a></p>
     <center>
      Username: <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
      Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">

     EOT;

     echo $form;
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Add database flag `isAdmin` and check it.

Comment: `mysql_escape_string` <== Please ***don't use the DEPRECATED `mysql` extension***. It was deprecated years ago, and is removed as of PHP7. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead. And use prepared statements.

Comment: add a column in your table as is_admin and chk this

Comment: what is the use of is_admin? and how to use is_admin sorry for the question guys im beginner here

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I want to point out to you here:

1. *mysql_escape_string* => You shoud be using PDO or mysqli as Elias mentioned. You can read about them [here](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should)
2. Your Select query shows like you don't have a flag for checking if the user is admin or just a user. You can add a column, something like ***is_Admin*** in the table and have that field store a value of 1 for Admin and 0 for other users. You should do this while entering users to the table. Since I see that you have ***register.php*** for registering users to the system, registering users would have 0 set and you would need to create separate registration for admin (or hardcode an entry in the db table row itself to set the is_Admin to 1 for a particular user, as per your case)
3. Once you have step 2 in place, now you will also check if is_Admin = 1 in your select statement. And once this is true, you are redirecting them to the ***adminhome.php*** page but it doesn't look like you are working with sessions. How are you making sure in **adminhome.php** page that it is an admin. Can anyone simply typing ***YOUR_URL/adminhome.php*** not come to this place? You need some role based access control which is explained [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/)
4. In your else statement for *num_rows*, just because the record is not found doesn't mean that the password is wrong. This may mislead the user trying to login. In fact, I go by the notion that system should never tell the user if which of their input (username or the password) is incorrect. If it is an unsuccessful login attempt, always output something like ***"Incorrect Username or Password"*** I see some sites out their that says: Username and Pasword incorrect => If both are incorrect. And just Password is incorrect (if only that is incorrect). I don't understand why it is done like that but that way you are already feeding the hacker(if this be the case) with 50% success and now will only need to try and get the password correct.